# Selecting field from referenced row of foreign key to same table

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-keys

I have a table where some rows have a field referencing another row in the same table through a foreign key. I would like to perform a select that returns another field from the referenced row instead of the meaningless key value.

Is there a way of doing this simply by somehow exploiting the foreign key or do I have to perform a join matching the fields as if no foreign key existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to self-join the table on the foreign key, give distinct names to both table copies, and then select the field you want:

```
SELECT t2.field_you_want 
FROM your_table AS t1 JOIN your_table AS t2 ON t1.foreign_key = t2.primary_key
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Simon, As in my case i have two table and using

```
SELECT s.student_name,s.student_profile_pic,a.attendance FROM 
smaced.studentattendanceclassx as a join smaced.student as s on s.student_id= a.student_attendancce
where a.school_attendance='school 2'
and a.tcsID_attendance='tcs 1';
```